# Is there a way to utilize a generic mapping in dozer instead of duplicating it?

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I am working on writing a dozer mapping to map fields from ClassA to ClassB. I have two use cases to address:

**Use Case 1:** Map all fields from ClassA to ClassB including "null" fields. This way I would be able to wipe out the value of a field from ClassB if it doesn't  have a value in ClassA.

**Use Case 2:** Map only "not null" fields from ClassA to ClassB. This way I would be able to preserve fields in ClassB even when they don't have values in ClassA.

Currently, I have to write two different mappings to address this situation. The mappings are exactly alike, apart from the value of the attribute "map-null".

**Question:**

Is there a way to avoid this duplication of mappings and set the "map-null" attribute at runtime and just have one generic mapping defined in Dozer?

```
 <mapping map-id="myMappings1" map-null="true">
            <class-a>test.ClassA</class-a>
            <class-b>test.ClassB</class-b>
            <field>
                <a>sampleVariable</a>
                <b>samplevariable</b>
            </field>
    </mapping>

<mapping map-id="myMappings2" map-null="false">
            <class-a>test.ClassA</class-a>
            <class-b>test.ClassB</class-b>
            <field>
                <a>sampleVariable</a>
                <b>samplevariable</b>
            </field>
        </mapping>
```

Comment: I think that is only possible if ClassA and ClassB inherit from the same class, then you would just map that super class. However if you just have 2 classes I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @j.con I have about 100 fields in ClassA and corresponding 100 fields in ClassB. And I would have many pairs of ClassA-ClassB in my application which would need similar handlings. I can go around writing multiple mappings, one with "map-null" as "true" and the other with "map-null" as "false", but that is going to increase the amount of mappings I have in my XML files. Also, if I need to change a mapping at a certain point in time, I would have to update it in both the mappings. I am just wondering if there is work-around to avoid this duplication.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand fully, but you shouldn't need to specify any mappings if variable names from ClassA match ClassB. Remove your mapping.xml file and do `x = (ClassA) dozer.build(classB, ClassA.class);` That should map both non null and null values, at that point you can extract null values in code if you don't want them.